# Making a triangle classifier for my intro to c++ class. I have a few questions

Tags: c++

For one, I'm trying to find a way to prevent the rest of the code from running if one of the if statements in the final set is executed.

I'm also wondering if there's a more efficient way of trying to determine the longest and median sides of the sides given.

My code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double sideOne = 1;
double sideTwo =2 ;
double sideThree = 3;

int main() 
{
    cout<<fixed;
    cout<<"Enter three numbers, corresponding to the side lengths of a triangle."<<endl;
    while (sideOne+sideTwo <= sideThree || sideThree+sideOne <= sideTwo || sideTwo+sideThree <= sideOne)
    {

        cout<<"Enter the first side length."<<endl;
        cin>>sideOne;
        cout<<"Enter the second side length."<<endl;
        cin>>sideTwo;
        cout<<"Enter the third side length."<<endl;
        cin>>sideThree;
        if (sideOne+sideTwo <= sideThree || sideThree+sideOne <= sideTwo || sideTwo+sideThree <= sideOne)
        {
            cout<<setprecision(3)<<"The input "<<sideOne<<", "<<sideTwo<<", "<<sideThree<<" does not satisfy the triangle inequality. Enter different side lengths."<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            double perimeter = sideOne + sideTwo + sideThree;
            double area = sqrt((perimeter/2)*((perimeter/2)-sideOne)*((perimeter/2)-sideTwo)*((perimeter/2)-sideThree));
            cout<<"The perimeter of your triangle is "<<setprecision(3)<<perimeter<<endl;
            cout<<"The area of your triangle is "<<setprecision(3)<<area<<endl;
            if (sideOne >= sideTwo && sideTwo >= sideThree)
            {
                cout<<"The longest side is "<<sideOne<<endl;
                cout<<"The median side is "<<sideTwo<<endl;
            }
            else if (sideTwo >= sideOne && sideOne >= sideThree)
            {
                cout<<"The longest side is "<<sideTwo<<endl;
                cout<<"The median side is "<<sideOne<<endl;

            }
            else if (sideThree >= sideOne && sideOne >= sideTwo)
            {
                cout<<"The longest side is "<<sideThree<<endl;
                cout<<"The median side is "<<sideOne<<endl;
            }
            else if (sideOne >= sideThree && sideThree >= sideTwo)
            {
                cout<<"The longest side is "<<sideOne<<endl;
                cout<<"The median side is "<<sideThree<<endl;
            }   
            else if (sideTwo >= sideThree && sideThree >= sideTwo)
            {
                cout<<"The longest side is "<<sideTwo<<endl;
                cout<<"The median side is "<<sideThree<<endl;
            }   
            else if (sideThree >= sideTwo && sideTwo >= sideOne)
            {
                cout<<"The longest side is "<<sideThree<<endl;
                cout<<"The median side is "<<sideTwo<<endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new to this, so novice vocab would be appreciated. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the other the rest of the function at any point by calling return. However a better alternative to the if, else if, else if ... structure is simply using a [switch case](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_switch.asp).

There are more efficient ways to find the longest and median sides. 
You are comparing the same sides several times.
An example of this is :

```
if (sideOne >= sideTwo && sideTwo >= sideThree)
...
else if (sideTwo >= sideThree && sideThree >= sideTwo)
```

Try to compare each side only once.